# RTSP and RTP for streaming from an IP Camera

Tags: rtsp, rtp

I have a simple application in c# that opens an RTSP session and sends the appropriate commands like DESCRIBE, SETUP, etc to control an RTP data stream.

My questions is this: does the TCP session (for the RTSP communication) have to stay open while streaming the data over RTP? Without going into details as to why, I'd like to be able to close the RTSP session after the RTP streaming is setup.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The short answer is yes you must keep the rtsp socket open.

If the stream is over TCP the RTP packet travels over the socket of the RTSP session. If the stream is over UDP the socket is used by the server to know if it should keep sending packet to the client because the UDP packet transmission does not have any feedback if the client is still alive.

Edited:

I think the answer marked correct is actually incorrect. In general, the cameras implement the RTSP protocol version 1 not version 2. In the 10 years that I have of experience in video surveillance systems I have found that several models of cameras stop sending RTP packets after closing the RTSP session socket .

Comment: I think you might be right?! The question is does the RTSP protocol demand it, but you hit more at the heart of my question. I see that it by default doesn't require it, but in my specific application your behavior is what i continue to experience. While it may not be "required" some implementations of firmware assume you'll keep the RTSP session open.

Answer (score 2):

[RFC 7826 Real-Time Streaming Protocol Version 2.0](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7826#section-10.2)

> A persistent connection is RECOMMENDED to be used for all
> transactions between the server and client, including messages for
> multiple RTSP sessions.  However, a persistent connection MAY be
> closed after a few message exchanges.  For example, a client may use
> a persistent connection for the initial SETUP and PLAY message
> exchanges in a session and then close the connection.  Later, when
> the client wishes to send a new request, such as a PAUSE for the
> session, a new connection would be opened.  This connection may be
> either transient or persistent.

So no, it is **not** required to be open while streaming data.